# How InstallAnywhere classify the error as fatal and non-fatal in install.log?

Tags: logging, error-handling, installanywhere

I use installAnywhere to build the installer. I double-click the installer, do next, next, the  application is installed. Now, when i go to, install.log, it has the fatal errors and non-fatal errors. I would like to know, on what basis, the errors are classified into fatal errors and non-fatal errors?

I see a similar post [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313351/when-logging-when-is-an-error-fatal)
Is installAnywhere also follows the same procedure to classify fatal and non-fatal errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

During installation, if there is an error and if the installation fails due to the error, it is a fatal error. On the other hand, during installation, if there is an error and if the installation completes in spite of an error, it is a non-fatal error.